# One DIV - three different contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On one of my web pages, I have buttons at the top, say A, B and C.

Below it, I would like to display varying content in a common DIV.   What is displayed is determined by which of the buttons is clicked.  There is no order in which the buttons can or will be clicked.

Each of Contents A, B and C are php driven pages with menu options, forms, etc.  The forms could be partly filled up after which User could navigate away from the page by clicking one of the above buttons and then clicking another button to come back to the form - I need to retain values of partially entered data.

Could someone share code (or point me in the right direction) where:

1) How do I ensure that Content A is displayed when page is initially loaded?

2) How do I define the page?

So far, I have defined a container DIV for the area where the content is to be displayed.  And thereafter three DIVs where each of the three php pages are loaded.

My problem is that All 3 DIVs are displayed and I can scroll up and down to view them.

I can handle 2 DIVs but 3 DIVs challenge me.

Thank you in advance.

Uttam

Comment: You'll have your show us your code for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout

```
<button class="toggleButton" data-target="div1">A</button>
<button class="toggleButton" data-target="div2">B</button>
<button class="toggleButton" data-target="div3">C</button>

<div id="div1" class="toggleDiv">
   Content A
</div>

<div id="div2" class="toggleDiv" style="display:none">
   Content B
</div>

<div id="div3" class="toggleDiv" style="display:none">
   Content C
</div>
```

The JavaScript code:

```
$(function(){

   $('.toggleButton').click(function(){

         var target = $('#' + $(this).attr('data-target'));
         $('.toggleDiv').not(target).hide();
         target.show();
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks - this gives me the core of what I will eventually develop.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this awesome jquery plugin which will add some kind of parallax effect to your page.

fullpage.js

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#4thpage